# application blocked for security reason java 8 update more 20

Tags: java, security, applet

I developed a java applet with java 8u55 in the running time by eclipse it hasnot any error but when I put it online I got the block for security reason 
I tried  https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml and https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml as you now in the security tab medium mode it is longer available also I added the URL in the site list but it is the same the java apple cannot run I will be happy to hear your suggestion :)
note: SSL is active on website 
thanks

Comment: *"I will be happy to hear your suggestion"* Abandon applets and instead develop a desktop app. based around `JFrame` ..

Comment: actually that was  the first an application by JFrame but I want to run it in the web page I change that to JApplet

Comment: *"..but I want to run it in the web page.."* Then you should have tried that 5 years ago, when it was actually practical to do so. See [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) for the bad news. You'd have a better chance of launching the `JFrame` from a **link in a web page** using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). The code will still need to be digitally signed, but at least it won't need to get past the hurdles that browsers present (or the complete lack of support by same).